# control the visibility of my button using COntrol key

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I want to control the visibility of my button in the Window of my c# WPF application.

.The button should be vissible only if the user clicks "alt+a+b".and buton shoulkd be invisible if the user clicks "alt+a+c". How can I do this .Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would create a Boolean property named `IsButtonVisible` in my view model that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

I'd then add some kind of handler method to handle the key presses (the `KeyDown` event):

```
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt) // Is Alt key pressed
{
    IsButtonVisible = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.B);
}
```

Now the `IsButtonVisible` property will be updated upon the correct key presses, we just need to use this value to affect the `Visibility` property of the `Button`. To do this, we will need to implement an `IValueConverter` to convert between the Boolean value and the `Visibility` value.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(bool)) return null;
        bool boolValue = (bool)value;
        return boolValue ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(Visibility)) return null;
        return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Now, we just need to bind to our Boolean property from the XAML `Button` declaration:

```
<Button Visibility="{Binding IsButtonVisible, 
    Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, 
    FallbackValue=Collapsed, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Comment: Since this is View Logic it would be one of the few times that could be implemented in the Code Behind of the View.

Comment: There is nothing that ties this code to the code behind. The `KeyDown` event can quite easily be handled with an `AttachedProperty` if you are that way inclined. However, it certainly *would* be a lot simpler to put it in the code behind. :)

Answer (score 1):

KeyDown or KeyPress event on your Form ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Bind the Visability of the Button to your ViewModel
2. Create a Command which is bound to the most top level of you application (MainWindow)
3. Assign the desired Hotkey to your command
4. Within the execute of the command change the Property value you used in step #1
5. Do the same for another command (one for visable another for invisable)

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the `KeyDown` event of your `WPF` Window. Then do this:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) && e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.A) && e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.B))
    {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
}
```